# Achivement item behavior for topbar on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, reputation, design, top-bar, stackexchange.com

Visiting the achivements popup in topbar on stackechange.com doesn't clear the green rep-increment icon:

> [image: rep-se]

Also I noticed that both achivements items are lighted on stackexchange.com, i.e. `+rep` and a "cup", but the light of cup is cleared after visiting the popup. May be I will add screenshot (or gif) later for this case, after earning more reputation.

Comment: @ShadowWizard you are super fast! :) as always

Comment: haha, my pleasure. :-D